# Iceberg schema not merging missing columns

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I am creating an Iceberg table using the following code in an AWS glue job:

```py
df.writeTo(f'glue_catalog.{DATABASE_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}') \
    .using('iceberg') \
    .tableProperty("location", TABLE_LOCATION) \
    .tableProperty("write.spark.accept-any-schema", "true") \
    .tableProperty("format-version", "2") \
    .createOrReplace()
```

The table is created and I can see it in Glue/LF and I can query it in Athena.

I have another job that is trying to upsert data using the following:

```py
df_upsert.createOrReplaceTempView("upsert_items")
upsert_query = f"""
MERGE INTO glue_catalog.{DATABASE_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} target
USING (SELECT * FROM upsert_items) updates
ON {join_condidtion}
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
spark.sql(upsert_query)
```

The GlueJob fails and says:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve my_column in MERGE command given columns [updates.col1, updates.col2, ...
```

How can I merge in new data when columns may be missing or columns may be added.  I thought Iceberg would handle this by filling in NULL for the missing/new columns because I set "write.spark.accept-any-schema" = true.

Running Spark version 3.3.0-amzn-1
AWS GlueJob v4
Iceberg v1.0.0

Comment: It looks like this is not supported yet. Here is the open ticket I found: https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/5556

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-writes/#schema-merge):

> The writer must enable the mergeSchema option.
> `data.writeTo("prod.db.sample").option("mergeSchema","true").append()`

This is not currently doable with `spark.sql("MERGE ...")`.

There is an open "feature request" [issue](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/5556) to handle this.

One "non optimal" solution, is to detect if a column is found in source while not there yet in target and then do and `ALTER TABLE target ADD COLUMN` before the MERGE statement. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️